# PHP preg_replace not working

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

okay so i got a script that removes "_" and replaces it with a space " " and it does not work i even used ereg_replace and eregi_replace none worked yet it works backwards( " ","_")

thanks a lot here is the script:

```
$namefixed = preg_replace("/_/", " ", $name);
```

and even

```
$namefixed = preg_replace("_", " ", $name);
```

Comment: Did you try [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace)?

Comment: `var_dump($name)` and see whether what's inside are underscores or spaces...

Comment: Your second `preg_replace` isn't expected to work properly since the pattern is not well-formed (delimiters are missing respectively your underscore is considered as opening delimiter and the closing delimiter is therefore missing).

Comment: +1 to Gumbo. Why in the world are you using a regular expression for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for regex, just use `str_replace()`.

```
$namefixed = str_replace("_", " ", $name);
```

If it only works backwards, then you're replacing spaces with underscores, which can only mean that there aren't any underscores in `$name` to replace in the first place, or you're searching in the wrong variable...